# Concourse ci setup on AWS ECS - No worker communication

Tags: concourse

Im having a go at setting up concourse on AWS ECS and hitting a bit of a wall.

I can see all containers running, and logging seems good.

The task definition is as close a port to the docker compose example as I can make it.

Im not seeing any heartbeat log entries, from workers or the web.

I know it's a very high level question but I needed to start somewhere

UPDATE

Ive also tried the example docker-compose file that is provided on a single ubuntu instance, same result. Same docker compose on my laptop works perfectly.

Comment: it seems you might want to check your security groups and network ACLs

Comment: hey @Ilja, ageed, my security groups are already wide open for testing purposes.

Comment: so it turns out i didnt have my certificate in the correct path. very hard to troubleshoot given the lack of logging.